# Converting ratio of cosines to tangent or cotangent

Tags: trigonometry

Given the function:

- $f : [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb{R}$
- $f(x) = \frac{\cos{x}}{\cos{(x-a)}}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Is it possible to convert it to some kind of translated / otherwise transformed $\tan{x}$ or $\cot{x}$?

I have plotted it for some values of $a$ and it looks like the above should be possible but I am at a loss when looking for the actual formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You have just to sum $\pm a$ in teh argument of the upper cosine
$$f(x)=\frac{\cos(x-a+a)}{\cos(x-a)}$$
and use the expression for the sum of angles
$$f(x)=\frac{\cos(x-a)\cos(a)-\sin(x-a)\sin(a)}{\cos(x-a)}=\cos(a)-\tan(x-a)\sin(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following.

$$f(x) = \frac{\cos{x}}{\cos{(x-a)}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\cos(x-a)}{cos(x)}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\cos(x)\cos(a)+\sin(x)\sin(a)}{cos(x)}}=\frac{1}{\cos(a)+\sin(a)\tan(x)}$$